# Steps allowed while dribbling without putting the ball down?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

Looking for clarification, in basketball how many steps are allowed *while* dribbling without putting the ball down? So in other words drag dribbles, floats, push cross, etc. According to the rules you *cannot* travel while dribbling. Since the dribble is live, when does ball in hand go too far? There’s nothing in the rules that’s clear on it. Obviously not talking about palming or hand under ball situations.

Answer (score 1):

The is no rule governing how many steps you can take per bounce when you are dribbling. You can dribble slowly and take 50 tiny quick steps between bounces if you want. Dribbling is dribbling.
Before you dribble or after the dribble, then the steps do count.
But then you arent dribbling anymore.

Comment: No, I get that, of course. I’m talking about ball is making contact with hand, is there a count? I’ve heard two, which would obviously match the max number allowed but I don’t know if that’s the case.

Comment: there is no count while dribbling. Either its a carry or no carry. the number of steps is irrelevant. So it all about hand under the ball , ball "stopped" or 2 hands.
Just concentrate on the whether the dribble handling is ok.  steps play no role here.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. That’s what I’ve always understood. So a good drag cross or push cross could be several steps as long as hand is on the side of the ball?